# Reading settings in spider scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote a small scrapy spider. Following is my code

```
class ElectronicsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "electronics"
    allowed_domains = ["www.olx.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.olx.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

My question is, I want to read the name,allowed_domains and start_urls  using setting. How can i do this?

I tried importing

```
 from scrapy.settings import Settings
```

also tried this

```
 def __init__(self,crawler):
        self.settings = crawler.settings
```

but I got none/error. Help me to read settings in my spider?

Comment: Because `name`, `allowed_domains` etc. are not settings, but spider class attributes. If you need to read settings from your spider code, then you can use just `self.settings` because it's prepopulated for you by Scrapy.

Comment: can you please help me to achieve this @Tomáš Linhart

Comment: I think my comment is self-contained. If you need definitive answer, you need to share more info about *from where* exactly you need to read *what*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

settings=get_project_settings()
print settings.get('NAME')
```

Using this code we  can  read data from settings file...

Answer (score 12):

`self.settings` is not yet initiated in `__init__()`. You can check `self.settings` in `start_requests()`.

```
def start_requests(self): 
    print self.settings
```

Answer (score 3):

I think if you want to access scrapy **settings.py** then answer from @Sellamani is good. But I guess name,allowed_domains and start_urls are not variables defined in settings.py. But if you want to have the same knd of arrangement then make your own config file like this, **yourown.cfg** :

```
[Name]
crawler_name=electronics

[DOMAINS]
allowed_domains=http://example.com
```

and then in your program use [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module like this to access **yourown.cfg** :

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('yourown.cfg') # Assuming it is at the same location
name=config.getint('NAME', 'crawler_name')
allowed_domains=config.getint('DOMAINS', 'allowed_domains')
```