# Why import scrapy.utils.project can load setting?

Tags: python, scrapy

Followed the post [Reading settings in spider scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230147/reading-settings-in-spider-scrapy) ,i load settings in `middlewares.py` successfully.

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings=get_project_settings()
```

I wonder why the settings can be loaded.

```
import scrapy.utils
dir(scrapy.utils)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'datatypes', 'decorators', 'deprecate', 'gz', 'iterators', 'misc', 'python', 'response', 'sitemap', 'spider', 'trackref', 'url']
dir(scrapy.utils.project)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'scrapy.utils' has no attribute 'project'
```

module 'scrapy.utils' has no attribute 'project',why `scrapy.utils.project` can load `get_project_settings` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at [utils.project.py on github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/project.py), you find:

```
from scrapy.settings import Settings
```

This means that settings gets imported and is available to the `scrapy.utils.project` module. To be specific to your question: the function `get_project_settings` is a part of `scrapy.utils.project`, so by that definition it is available to `scrapy.utils.project`. `Scrapy.utils` does not need to have a settings attribute in order for `scrapy.utils.project` to do its work, as it can import and define whatever it needs to do its work.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy is an application framework for writing web spiders that crawl web sites and extract data from them. Scrapy utils are just a set utilities for loaders, extensions and more.

If you are inside a Scrapy project there are some additional helpers you can use to import those components within the project. You can automatically import and use **get_project_settings** to get a Settings instance with your project settings.

That's how it works.

Comment: No key points about my issue,i feel,ask more ,points more ,good luck to you.